# Set two keys for one value in Hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-hash

Let's say I have a hash:

```
{
  first: :value1,
  second: :value1,
  third: :value2 
}
```

During `.map` I need to eliminate duplicates so it should be either `first` or `second` only. Is it possible to have some workaround like:

```
{
  (:first || :second) => :value1,
  third: :value2 
}
```

If not, how can I remove key duplicates in a hash based on condition? Is it possible to pass a condition into the `.uniq` block?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```rb
hsh =
  {
    first: :value1,
    second: :value1,
    third: :value2 
  }

hsh.uniq { _2 }.to_h
# => {:first=>:value1, :third=>:value2}
```

Firstly call `uniq` with block and [numbered parameter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Numbered+parameters). It returns array of arrays where second elements are unique (take first pair)

```rb
ary = hsh.uniq { _2 }
# => [[:first, :value1], [:third, :value2]]
```

And convert array to hash

```rb
ary.to_h
# => {:first=>:value1, :third=>:value2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to pass a block to the `#uniq` method.

https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq

You can apply something like:

```rb
hash.uniq { |_k, v| v }
```

or shorter:

```rb
hash.uniq(&:last)
```

Also, another correct solution if you don't need the keys is to simply take the values:

```rb
hash.values.uniq
```

The second recommendation of yours is valid Ruby code, but incorrect, as it removes one key and evaluates to the following:

```rb
irb(main):004:0> {
  (:first || :second) => :value1,
  third: :value2
}
=> {:first=>:value1, :third=>:value2}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have the second recommendation with both of them, eliminating the one that is `nil` only? So for example if hash[:first] is nil I'd use hash[:second] instead?

Comment: Are you referring to `hash.uniq(&:last)`? You can call `#select(&:last)` to remove all `nil` values.

Comment: `uniq` returns array, so you need to convert it to hash

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Hash#invert`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Hash:invert), to make the hash point from each unique value to a single key. It will keep the last key for each value:

```rb
hash = {
  first: :value1,
  second: :value1,
  third: :value2 
}

hash.invert
# => {
#   :value1=> :second,
#   :value2=> :third
# }
```

Then you can iterate over that or use it any way you like.

Comment: Good idea, but as I understand OP wants first value